# How many bits are needed to encode the following?

Tags: binary, binary-operations

1) Students in this section (there are 57)

2) Students in this class (there are 117)

**3) The range from 327 to 234,341 inclusive.**

4) The range from 0 to 1,024 inclusive.

1,2,and 4 are trivial (at least I believe so, if they are 6, 7, and 11)

However, number 3 I am unsure of. Obviously you could see how many bits you need to encode up to 234,341, but I think there is a way to do this problem and reduce the number of bits needed, I just don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

You can encode $x-327$ instead of $x$, and add $327$ to the decoded value.

Comment: Ahh, duh, that was fairly obvious, thank you!

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark.  That way, it leaves the unsolved queue.